# Determine if the following series converges or diverges using the alternating series test.

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{4}{3}}}$$

Using the $p$-series test I know that this converges. But how would I use the alternating series to solve this?

Comment: Do you know what the alternating series test states?

Answer (score 0):

If in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n,\ \sum\left|a_n\right|$ converges,which in this case it does as it's a p-series with p>0, we call the series absolutely convergent (i.e. it converges even if it alternates.

If it was however not absolutely convergant,
we would use the leibniz test,
which states that if $a_n$ is a decreasing series, that is $\left|a_{n+1}\right|<\left|a_n\right|$ for all n, then the series converges conditionally.

Comment: The series here in question is absolute convergent

Comment: Right,I didn't look properly and misread 4/3 as 1/3. Let me fix that. Thank you